# Using Regex in SQL Server, I couldn't solve the following problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have strings like that

OPEN SYSTEMS SUB GR (GM/BTIB(1111)/BTITDBL(2222)/BTVY(4444)/ACSVTYSAG)

and I need to extract 2222 from it.

What I was doing is this on the GROUPS String:

```
    SUBSTRING(GROUPS, CHARINDEX('(',GROUPS, CHARINDEX('(',GROUPS, CHARINDEX('(',GROUPS,0)+1)+1)+1, 4 ) AS GroupNo
```

However I see that it is not very efficient and I ve been told to do it using the regex. I couldn't solve it. I hope if anyone can help me with it. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some other examples of what the string might hold? If it's always exactly as you have there then you could simply do a SUBSTRING with the exact indexes for the start and end of the number, but I'm guessing that's not the case.

Comment: String structere outlook is exactly the same. The same number of pharanthesis, and same number of numbers. But sometimes groups names can be longer and that is why I can't do a constant substring. Here is another example: CRM SUB GR (GRM/BTB(2232)/BITDL(4443)/BVY(1123)/ACSV)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I understand now what you need everyting starting in the 3rd parentheses and then 4 digits long?

take a look at

```
Declare @Data varchar(8000)

select @Data='OPEN SYSTEMS SUB GR (GM/BTIB(1111)/BTITDBL(2222)/BTVY(4444)/ACSVTYSAG)'

select left(parsename(left(replace(@data,'(','.'),
    len(@data) - PATINDEX('%(%',reverse(@data))),1),4)
```

Comment: Hello, this seems not to be a regex but it works, however it is slower than the substring about 2/3.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not natively support regular expressions.

You can, however, use CLR integration to add a .NET stored procedure which can use regular expressions.  See [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/) for a nice explanation.